# Building a music player for both android and Desktop at the same time

Tags: java, android, user-interface, desktop

I'm going to build a music player working on both Android and Desktops. It won't be anything special, I'm doing it more to training myself and know more or less what problems I might encounter if I want to do a real app/program one day. Therefore, since I'm already rather decent at web technologies, I'll try to use something else: Java.

---

My app / program with have to

- be able to read music files and play them (I'm planning on reading the files myself, meaning that I only need to be able to read "raw" sound, WAV or such)
- be able to write to music files (to change tags)
- be able to communicate with another instance of the program on another device that's on the same network (I want to be able to use my phone as a remote control and my pc as a remote control for my phone)
- If possible, show some play/pause buttons on the screen even if it's locked (probably just on android)

---

And this is where I need your help: What you I do to write as little "device specific" code as possible?

It's obvious I can reuse classes used to encode/decode some music types. Finding the files, reading them, writing them, playing raw sound and connection to the network will be easy to abstract if needed.

But then there is the UI and it looks like if I don't plan carefully, I'll have to do it twice... I've seen [libGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/index.html) but they kinda insist a lot on the fact it's for games...

All I need is some way to build a simple UI (a few buttons, the cover of the albums) that'd work for both the desktop and the phone.

Should I use libGDX, the "normal" libs (*WT, Swing, neither of which seem to be "compatible" with Android) or something else?

---

I'd also like to request as few permissions as possible. Meaning that I'd like to have a base music player that only request access to the sd card, and then features requiring additional permissions would be added as other apps/programs or addons.

From what I understood, the only way to achieve this is to create a second app and make the user install it. I think I'll manage to make the two apps communicate (with Intent?) but is it really the only solution?

---

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could consider building the app with something such as Phonegap: http://phonegap.com/ This would let you use your web technologies strength and write a very slim layer of device specific code if any at all!

As for getting a phonegap app to run on the desktop....you could use something like :http://ripple.incubator.apache.org/ to have it run on the desktop. I know this is slightly different and you wanted to tackle writing something in Java - however this is the way mobile development is moving so you may want to get started like this!

Comment: I'm doing this to learn new things in Java. I do NOT want to use web technologies. And if I did do it with web technologies, I'd package it as an app/extension for browsers instead of using something like that toget it to run on desktop.

Comment: Well in that case I propose you have workout how to play files using android - then how you play files using standard Java. Those are the only bits where I think there will be bespoke code the rest of the implementation can probably be shared. There will also be wrapper android activity classes which wont play any part in your desktop implementation.

Best thing to do would be to create a join set of packages, an android native package / project and a desktop native package / project and link to the shared code through including the projects at build time using eclipse.

Comment: Yes. But I wanted to know how to write the UI so that I could share it.

Comment: As far as I know thats impossible. Unless you go down my original route....of using web technologies.